# Как сделать адаптивность сайту?

Tags: javascript, html, css, адаптивность

Мне срочно нужно сделать сайт адаптивным, чтобы он отображался нормально на всех устройствах, скажите пожалуйста как быстро это сделать и что надо добавить, код большой, поэтому просто подскажите какие свойства или что-то еще добавлять.

```css
*{
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    /* ie8 */
}

body {
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}


#preloader {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255) url(images/Ripple.gif) no-repeat center center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 90px;
    line-height: 59px;
    /* identical to box height */
    
    
    color: rgba(37, 210, 127, 1)
}

.loadingio-spinner-spinner-4gg88ylyvxk {
margin: 0 auto;
}

.zagruzka {
    margin-top: 690px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: 135px;
    z-index: 2;
    background: rgba(37, 210, 127, 0.94);
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.navigation {
    height: 135px;
}

.cities {
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 6%;
    width: 100%;
}

.logo {
position: absolute;
display: flex;
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 0;
bottom: 0
}

.round {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 86px;
    height: 86px;
    margin-left: 213px;
    top: 25px;

    border: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 100px;

}

.dollarSign {
    font-family: 'Inter';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 61px;
    /* identical to box height */
    padding-top: 10px;


    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.logoText {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 39px;
    width: 395px;
    height: 59px;
    color: white;
}

.logoName {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 59px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.logoName:hover {
    text-shadow: 0px 5px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30);
    background-origin: 0px 5px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30);
    transition: 1s;
}

.logoName:not(:hover) {
    transition: 1s;
}

/* Animation */
.area {
    background: #ffffff56;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #8f94fb, #4e54c8);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 40px;
z-index: -5;

}

.circles {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -5;
    top:50px
    
}

.circles li {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    z-index: -5;
    background: rgba(10, 255, 161, 0.466);
    animation: animate 25s linear infinite;
    bottom: -150px;

}

.circles li:nth-child(1) {
    left: 25%;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    z-index: -5;
    animation-delay: 0s;

}


.circles li:nth-child(2) {
    left: 10%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    z-index: -5;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-duration: 12s;
   
}

.circles li:nth-child(3) {
    left: 70%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    z-index: -5;
    animation-delay: 4s;
 
}

.circles li:nth-child(4) {
    left: 40%;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    z-index: -5;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-duration: 18s;
    
}

.circles li:nth-child(5) {
    left: 65%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    z-index: -5;
    animation-delay: 0s;

}

.circles li:nth-child(6) {
    left: 75%;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    z-index: -5;
    animation-delay: 3s;

}

.circles li:nth-child(7) {
    left: 35%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    z-index: -5;
    animation-delay: 7s;

}

.circles li:nth-child(8) {
    left: 50%;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    animation-delay: 15s;
    z-index: -5;
    animation-duration: 45s;

}

.circles li:nth-child(9) {
    left: 20%;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    z-index: -5;
    animation-duration: 35s;

}

.circles li:nth-child(10) {
    left: 85%;
    width: 150px;
    z-index: -5;
    height: 150px;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-duration: 11s;

}



@keyframes animate {

    0% {
        transform: translateY(0) rotate(0deg);
        opacity: 1;
        border-radius: 0;
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateY(-1000px) rotate(720deg);
        opacity: 0;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }

}

/* Animation End */

/* Селектор языка */

.selected-lang {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    justify-content: space-between;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 35px;
    
    color: #ffffff;

}

.selected-lang-img {
    display: block;
    width: 26px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-left: 7px;
}

.triangle {
    border: 7px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 113px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    border-top: 7px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
    width: 12.5px;
    height: 6.5px;
}

.lang-menu {
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0px;
    position: relative;
}

.languages {
    position: absolute;
    left: 803.5px;
    top: 50px;
}

.lang-menu ul {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 60px;
    width: 108px;
    padding-right: 38px;
    background-color: #fff;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3s);
box-shadow: 0 0 15px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
border-radius: 5px;
display: none;
}

.lang-menu ul:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
   top: -40px;
   right: 34px;
    border: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.lang-menu ul li {
list-style: none;
width: 108px;
}

.lang-menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 0px;
}

.lang-menu ul li a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(228, 228, 228);
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.lang-menu:hover ul {
    transition: 1s;
    display: block;
}

.profile {
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 35px;
    width: 207px;
    height: 35px;
    margin-left: 1040px;
    top: 51px;
}

.LK {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

.profile:before {
    content: '';
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
    left: -40px;
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(images/profile.png)
}

.searching {
    z-index: 20;
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    left: 1300px;
    top: 63px;
}

#content {
    z-index: 20;
    position: absolute;
    height: 0px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: 170px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#content.on {
    z-index: 20;
    -webkit-animation-name: in-out;
    animation-name: in-out;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.7s;
    animation-duration: 0.7s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

input {
    z-index: 20;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 4px solid #ffffff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: Roboto;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out, border-radius 0.8s ease-in-out,
        padding 0.2s;
    transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out, border-radius 0.8s ease-in-out,
        padding 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.4s;
    transition-delay: 0.4s;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
}

.search {
    z-index: 20;
    background: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 40px;
    top: -10px;
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 100%;
    outline: 0;
    border: 0;
    color: inherit;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-105%, -50%);
}

.search:before {
    z-index: 20;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    margin-top: 26px;
    margin-left: 17px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.close {
    z-index: 20;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.4s;
    transition-delay: 0.4s;
}

.close:before {
    z-index: 20;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 20   px;
    height: 4px;
    margin-top: 12.5px;
    margin-left: -13px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title>Предприниматели Казахстана</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="preloader">
      <span class="zagruzka">ENTERPRENEUR.KZ</span>
    </div>
    <!-- Header -->
    <header>
      <div class="navigation">
        <img src="images/Cities.png" alt="Cities" class="cities" />
        <div class="logo">
          <div class="round"><p class="dollarSign">₸</p></div>
          <div class="logoText">
            <p class="logoName" onclick="document.location='mainpage.html'">
              ENTERPRENEUR.KZ
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="languages">
          <div class="lang-menu">
            <div class="selected-lang">
              Язык:
              <img
                class="selected-lang-img"
                src="images/russia.png"
                width="26px"
                height="25px"
              />
              <div class="triangle"></div>
            </div>
            <ul class="bgLang">
              <li>
                <a
                  ><img
                    src="images/kazakhstan.png"
                    alt="KZ"
                    width="30px"
                    height="30px"
                /></a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a
                  ><img
                    src="images/united-kingdom.png"
                    alt="UK"
                    width="30px"
                    height="30px"
                /></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="profile"><a href="gg" class="LK">Личный кабинет</a></div>
        <div class="searching">
          <form id="content">
            <input type="text" name="input" class="input" id="search-input" />
            <button type="reset" class="search" id="search-btn"></button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <script src="searchbox.js"></script>
        <div id="menuToggle">
          <input type="checkbox" />
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <ul id="menu">
            <a href="mainpage.html">
              <li>Главная</li>
            </a>
            <a href="">
              <li>О нас</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li>Новости</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li>Форум</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li>Контакты</li>
            </a>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Конец navigation -->
    </header>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <div class="mainContent">
      <div class="maintext">
        <h1 class="zagolovok">
          Предприниматели - будущее <span class="colortext">Казахстана!</span>
        </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="paragraph">
        <p class="describing">
          Enterpreneur.kz - Онлайн площадка, цель которой состоит в том, чтобы
          объединить всех молодых предпринимателей со всего Казахстана. Именно
          здесь будут зарождаться и реализоваться инновационные идеи.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="buttonRed">
        <button class="Podr" onclick="document.location='mainpage.html#about'">
          ПОДРОБНЕЕ
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="buttonGreen"><button class="Forum">ФОРУМ</button></div>
      <div class="pictures">
        <div class="blob">
          <img src="images/blob1.png" alt="BLOB" />
        </div>
        <div class="blob2">
          <img src="images/blob2.png" alt="blob2" />
        </div>
        <div class="hand">
          <img src="images/Hand.png" alt="hand" />
        </div>
        <div class="rocket">
          <img src="images/Rocket.png" alt="rocket" />
        </div>
        <div class="shadow">
          <img src="images/Rocketshadow.png" alt="RS" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="area">
        <ul class="circles">
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="separator"><div class="line"></div></div>
    <div class="aboutUs">
      <div class="aboutUsHeader">
        <h1 class="oNas"><a name="about">О НАС</a></h1>
      </div>
      <div class="textAbout">
        <p class="paragraphAbout">
          <span class="colorAb">ENTERPRENEUR.KZ</span> - откроет возможность
          показать себя. Реализуй, создавай и предлагай вместе с другими
          участниками огромного проекта уже сегодня. Вместе мы творим будущее
          нашей любимой страны.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="shield">
        <img src="images/shield.png" alt="shield" class="shieldIcon" />
        <div class="textReliability">Надежность</div>
      </div>
      <div class="stats">
        <img src="images/stats.png" alt="stats" class="statsIcon" />
        <div class="textStats">Развитие</div>
      </div>
      <div class="atom">
        <img src="images/atom.png" alt="atom" class="atomIcon" />
        <div class="textAtom">Инновационность</div>
      </div>
      <div class="bg">
        <img
          src="images/bg.png"
          alt="BG"
          class="bgimg"
          width="100%"
          height="1046px"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="laptop">
        <img src="images/laptop.png" alt="laptop" class="laptopPic" />
      </div>
      <div class="cards">
        <img src="images/cards.png" alt="cards" class="cardsPic" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Конец about us -->
    <div class="separator2"><div class="line2"></div></div>
    <div class="news">
      <div class="newsHeader">
        <h1 class="novosti"><a name="newsName">Новости</a></h1>
        <div class="newscard1">
          <img src="images/news1.png" alt="news1" class="newsphoto1" />
          <h2 class="headnews2">
            Эксперт МВФ дал рекомендации по восстановлению экономики в
            Казахстане
          </h2>
          <p class="newsdate">27 сентября 2021, 17:32</p>
          <a href="https://tengrinews.kz/" class="tengrilink1">tengrinews.kz</a>
          <p class="newspar1">
            Директор департамента стран Ближнего Востока и Центральной Азии
            Джихад Азур считает, что в странах Центральной Азии, в том числе в
            Казахстане, реформирование государственных предприятий приведет...
          </p>
          <button class="newsbutton1">ЧИТАТЬ</button>
        </div>
        <!-- Конец newscard -->
        <!-- Конец newsHeader -->
      </div>
      <div class="backa">
        <img
          src="images/triangles.png"
          alt="backa"
          width="100%px"
          height="946px"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="newscard2">
        <img src="images/news2.png" alt="news2" class="newsimg2" />
        <h2 class="headnews3">
          Moody’s подтвердило рейтинги Kaspi Bank. Прогноз – "Стабильный"
        </h2>
        <p class="newsdate2">13 апреля 2022, 09:15</p>
        <a href="https://tengrinews.kz/" class="tengrilink2">tengrinews.kz</a>
        <p class="newspar2">
          Moody’s подтвердило долгосрочный рейтинг депозитов в национальной и
          иностранной валюте и долгосрочный рейтинг риска контрагента Kaspi Bank
          на уровне Ba1. Прогноз "Стабильный" отражает мнение агентства о
          дальнейшем...
        </p>
        <button class="newsbutton2">ЧИТАТЬ</button>
      </div>
      <div class="newscard3">
        <img src="images/news3.png" alt="news3" class="newsimg3" />
        <h2 class="headnews4">
          Почему президентские резервисты претендуют на работу в "Казахтелекоме"
        </h2>
        <p class="newsdate3">11 апреля 2022, 16:00</p>
        <a href="https://tengrinews.kz/" class="tengrilink3">tengrinews.kz</a>
        <p class="newspar3">
          Напомним, что Президентский молодежный кадровый резерв возник в 2019
          году по инициативе Касым-Жомарта Токаева как ресурс, способный
          сформировать новую кадровую элиту...
        </p>
        <button class="newsbutton3">ЧИТАТЬ</button>
      </div>
      <div class="allnews">ВСЕ НОВОСТИ</div>
    </div>
    <script>
      setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById("preloader").style.display = "none";
      }, 1500);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Прочесть учебник по адаптивной верстке и переделать весь ваш css как минимум :)

Comment: "просто подскажите какие свойства или что-то еще добавлять" -- к сожалению это так не работает.

Comment: Переписать всё. Например на flex контейнерах.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

под разные размеры можешь делать так